# Create automatic partition for S3 year/month/day/hour folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, database-partitioning

My S3 bucket has the following structure.

```
's3://st.pix/year/month/day/hour' for example
's3://st.pix/2022/09/01/06'
```

So I tried to create a partition table on this bucket using this code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acco`.`Accesn` (

  `ad_id` string,

) 
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string , hour string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://st.pix/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false','compressionType'='gzip');
```

and right after run

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE Accesn
```

But unfortunately, this query gets no result.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `acco`.`Accesn` where year ='2022' and month= '03' and day ='01' and hour ='01'
```

Can I use `${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/` in my `LOCATION` ?
If no, what are the options to do it dynamically and not using `ALTER TABLE ..  ADD PARTITION` for a specific partition.

Comment: If you do not wish to use `ADD PARTITION`, then the data will need to be stored in Hive format: `year=2021/month=01/day=26/...)`

Comment: Is there an option to use add partition for all and not menually for every partition? if yes, how?

Comment: Nope. The only automatic way to add all partitions is with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`, but that is not compatible with your naming scheme because the folder names do not contain enough information to tell Athena how it is being partitioned. You could write a program that scans the S3 bucket to look for Prefixes and then call `ADD PARTITION` in Athena, but you'd need to code that yourself. This _might_ be doing that: [Add Newly Created Partitions Programmatically into AWS Athena schema](https://medium.com/swlh/add-newly-created-partitions-programmatically-into-aws-athena-schema-d773722a228e)

Comment: Is there an option to do it in the Athena? can I use month(currentdate()) and concat() inside the location?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, but no -- Athena can only run queries. You would need to put any logic concerning Amazon S3 _outside_ of Amazon Athena.